# Can't check for empty text in domain constraint

Tags: postgresql, psql

I have a domain like so

```
create domain foo as text                                                   
     constraint not_blank check (char_length(value) > 0)                      
     constraint min_length check (char_length(value) > 1)                
     constraint suggested_length check (char_length(value) < 8)                                                                                                                                                   
     constraint max_length check (char_length(value) < 10);
```

And I test it as such

```
 select * from length (''::foo);
 select * from length ('1'::foo);
 select * from length ('12345678'::foo);
 select * from length ('1234567890'::foo);
```

Why is it that I catch the suggested vs max length correctly, but I can't catch the blank input correctly?

```
test=#  select * from length (''::foo);
ERROR:  value for domain foo violates check constraint "min_length"
test=#  select * from length ('1'::foo);
ERROR:  value for domain foo violates check constraint "min_length"
test=#  select * from length ('12345678'::foo);
ERROR:  value for domain foo violates check constraint "suggested_length"
test=#  select * from length ('1234567890'::foo);
ERROR:  value for domain foo violates check constraint "max_length"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The empty string violates the first three check constraints, so it is sort of random which of the constraints gets reported in the error.

You are aware that these constraints contradict each other, right?

If you want several conditions to be tested in a certain order, I recommend using a trigger that tests the conditions one after the other and throws an appropriate exception.

Comment: I thought they would be tested for in order like if (>0) print('non zero'), elif (>1) print ('non greater than 1')...

Comment: Is there a way to test if it is blank without the >1 length getting triggered?

Comment: You could use a trigger as suggested in my extended answer.